# Getting "Can't set headers after they are sent error" in PassportJS authentication middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, jmeter, azure-active-directory, passport.js

I have several NodeJS APIs and they need Azure AD authentication. I used PassportJS along with passport-azure-ad node package for that. I am getting **Can't set headers after they are sent** error when I am doing load test using JMeter and reaching X number of users. The error is not occurring in normal usage.

I checked the code, I didn't come across any place where response object is modified after it's sent. Below given is stripped version of code and exception stacktrace. I have also put the comment within code for line of number which is part of stacktrace. Please guide me what I am doing wrong. I can add further details if needed.

**Stacktrace**

```
at AppInsightsAsyncCorrelatedErrorWrapper.ZoneAwareError (.....\node_modules\applicationinsights\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:811:33)
at new AppInsightsAsyncCorrelatedErrorWrapper (.....\node_modules\applicationinsights\out\AutoCollection\CorrelationContextManager.js:193:18)
at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:491:11)
at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:498:3)
at ServerResponse.header (.....\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:767:10)
at ServerResponse.send (.....\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
at ServerResponse.json (.....\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
at myPassport.authenticate (.....\.....\common\authentication-middleware.js:252:47)
at Strategy.strategy.error (.....\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:353:18)
at verified (.....\node_modules\passport-azure-ad\lib\bearerstrategy.js:550:23)
at .....\.....\common\authentication-middleware.js:165:29
at Request.request [as _callback] (.....\.....\currentUserUtil.js:23:7)
at self.callback (.....\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (.....\node_modules\applicationinsights\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:275:35)
at Zone.runTask (.....\node_modules\applicationinsights\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:151:47)
```

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const entityRoute = require('./entity-api');

const authMiddleWare = require('../common/authentication-middleware');
authMiddleWare.initializeAuthentication();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json({ item: 'My RESTful API - Version 1.0.0' });
})
.use('/entity', function(req, res, next) {
    authMiddleWare.ensureAuthentication(req, res, next);
}, entityRoute);

module.exports = app;
```

**authentication-middleware.js**

```
var Passport = require('passport').Passport;
var myPassport = new Passport();
let ODICBearerStrategy = require('passport-azure-ad').BearerStrategy;
const currentUserUtil = require('./currentUserUtil');

const _initializeAuthentication = function() {
    myPassport.use(validateTokenMiddleware());
}

const validateTokenMiddleware = function() {
    var options = {
        // several values here
    };
    var bearerStrategy = new ODICBearerStrategy(options,
        function(req, decodedToken, done) {
            try {
                if (decodedToken && decodedToken.oid) {
                    currentUserUtil.getCurrentUserByOid(decodedToken.oid, req.get('authorization'), function(result) {
                        if (result && result.oid == decodedToken.oid) {
                            done(null, {}, decodedToken);
                        } else if (result && !result.Status && decodedToken.name && decodedToken.name.toLowerCase() == "superadmin") {
                            done(null, {}, decodedToken);
                        } else {
                            // below line is part of stacktrace - authentication-middleware.js:165:29
                            done("Access Denied", "Access Denied", "Access Denied");
                        }
                    })
                } else {
                    done("Access Denied", "Access Denied", "Access Denied");
                }
            } catch (ex) {
                done("Access Denied", "Access Denied", "Access Denied");
            }
        }
    );
    return bearerStrategy;
};

const _ensureAuthentication = function(req, res, next) {
    myPassport.authenticate('oauth-bearer', {
        session: false
    }, (err, user, info) => {
        if (err || !user) {
            let errorMsg = "Token Missing : Access Denied";
            if (info) {
                if (info.indexOf('expired') !== -1) {
                    errorMsg = "Token Expired :  Access Denied";
                } else if (info.indexOf('did not receive a token') !== -1) {
                    errorMsg = "Token Invalid : Access Denied"
                } else if (info.indexOf('invalid') !== -1) {
                    errorMsg = "Token Invalid : Access Denied"
                }
            }
            // below line is part of stacktrace - authentication-middleware.js:252:47
            return res.status(401).json({
                "Result": "False",
                "userMessage": errorMsg
            });
        } else {
            return next();
        }
    })(req, res, next);
}

module.exports = {
    initializeAuthentication: _initializeAuthentication,
    ensureAuthentication: _ensureAuthentication
}
```

**currentUserUtil.js**

```
var request = require("request");

// Returns the user object based on Azure AD OID (object ID)
function _getCurrentUserByOid(oid, token, callback) {
    var config_par = {
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": {
            "authorization": token
        },
        "url": `https://example.com/api/user/oid/${oid}`,
    }
    request(config_par, (error, response, body) => {
        if (error) {
            callback({ "Status": false });
        }
        try {
            callback(JSON.parse(body));
        } catch (ex) {
            // below line is part of stacktrace - currentUserUtil.js:23:7
            callback({ "Status": false });
        }
    });
}

module.exports = {
    getCurrentUserByOid: _getCurrentUserByOid
}
```

Comment: I am not sure, but i think the issue is with you calling the callback multiple times in the `_getCurrentUserByOid` function. When request function throws an error, you call the callback, but you do not stop the execution of the rest of the script within it, you try to parse the body, fail because there was error earlier, and you call callback with status false once again in the catch block

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski good observation, I will move that try...catch into else part. Thanks!